# After building first computer, powering on works for only 2 seconds until it switches on and off infinitely

Tags: boot, power-supply, computer-building

I have built my own pc, with z87x - UD4H / i5 4670k / 770 GTX.

- I installed the CPU / stock fan / connected it to the MOBO.
- Connected the 24 pin power supply
- Connected the GPU / Ram / Sonar DX audio
- Front panel connectors / front usb / 2 hard drives

The power supply is an old one, I think a 700w Gigabyte or something, it was very expensive when I bought it (worked just moments ago in my old pc).

When I plug the power cable and switch the PSU on, the ethernet cable is glowing, so power is getting trough all right, however when I switch it on, it starts spinning the fans, then after like 2 seconds it dies ... then it starts BY ITSELF again, and dies and so on and so forth.

What could this be ? What can I troubleshoot, should I remove the GPU and see if the PSU can handle the load (how do I do this, just remove the 6 & 8 pin connectors?)

Could I have damaged the CPU (I don't think I did, but I dread doing that).

**EDIT:** Removed the GPU, same problem, does not look like PSU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some basic hardware troubleshooting: Take everything out but the CPU and the motherboard.  Boot it, does it beep like you have no RAM and/or no Video? If so, that's good since it doesn't have RAM or video..  If it doesn't beep, try reseating the CPU, if that doesn't help, then you most likely have a bad motherboard.

Ok, assuming it beeps -- now does it stay on? If so, that's good too, means your motherboard and CPU most likely aren't the problem.  Now start adding hardware back in one piece at a time, until the problem starts again.  That should narrow it down for you.

Comment: I shall do this, curently it does not beep at all. I have to know this ASAP: Does this sound like I may have damaged the CPU (again, no reason to think this but I am scared).

Comment: CPU's are pretty hard to damage as long as you take care when handling and installing them.  If you're scared to do anything, pack it up and take it to a professional to get it repaired.

Comment: Everything is out except the CPU. No beep. What should I look for at the CPU or just reset it ?

Comment: Take it out, ensure no pins are bent/damaged in the socket, and that there's no debris in the socket or on the contact side of the CPU.  Ensure you don't have gobs of heat-sink compound everywhere, etc. If the PCU seems fine, try another (known good) PSU, if it acts the same way you more than likely have a defective motherboard.  If you're going to tell me you don't have spare parts (like a PSU) around to try then, again, pack it up and take it to a professional, as a necessary part of building and repairing computers is having spare parts to swap in for testing.

Comment: I wish I could tell if the CPU pins are bent but they are simply too small. I doubt that they are. It does saund like a faulty MOBO either way. Thank you.